# Representation of Vectors in Handwritten Work

Tags: notation, vectors

There is a particular note in my textbook which says:

> When you represent vectors by single letters in handwritten work, you should write them as $\underset{\sim}{A}$

I haven't seen this form of notation being used elsewhere; thoughts on whether or not I should use it (for an exam)?

Comment: You can use all notations you want as far as you clearly define them.

Comment: For exams: Copy what your professor does (provided you have any examples there; you can also ask them). Otherwise, do what you prefer, though a squiggly underline is completely new to me as well. (Underlining, little arrows on top or no special marking are all much more common, I think.)

Comment: (If grading is done reasonably, whether you underline your vectors should be irrelevant.)

Comment: This is the traditional way of marking up "boldface" for a printer.